# CSS Question: floated beneath block. Possible to get floated to top?

Tags: css, css-float

I searched for an answer. Couldn't find so here goes:

I'm familiar with all the basic 2 column layouts. What I need is a floated column to be at the top without giving the block element above it (in the page flow) a margin.

See http://jsfiddle.net/W3DEC/7/ for an example. I'd like the sidebar to be on top, meaning overlapping, the h1.

The reason I need this, is because I'm trying to build a page that sometimes has a sidebar and sometimes doesn't, so I don't want to give the top element a fixed width (other than that dictated by it's container) or a margin.

This is unlike the usual fixed-sidebar+fluid-center situation, because those fluid center **always** have those fixed sidebars.

I hope all this is clear.

Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
#sidebar {
    background-color: LightBlue;
   position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;

}
```

Comment: Thanks! The one caveat with this is that #sidebar cannot have a transparent bg. Correct?  Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Another issue: if #sidebar has more content (thus, height) than the block, it'll overlay the next element. The usual fixes for floated elements aren't working. Any ideas?